# Merge null value

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i need to merge 1st row and 2nd row. 3 rd and 4th row. below is what i already get.
because of the currency is NULL so it does not combined.

[image: this is the result i get for now.]

[image: this is what i need]

below is my current code. so how to merge them?

```
SELECT 
  decode(substr(o.tran_no,1,1), 'B', 'BUY', 'S', 'SELL') BS_IND,
  COUNT(decode(substr(o.tran_no,1,1), 'B', 'BUY')) BUY,
  COUNT(decode(substr(o.tran_no,1,1),'S', 'SELL')) SELL,
  DECODE(D.CURRENCY,NULL,'MYR','MYR') CURRENCY3,
  DECODE(D.CURRENCY,'MYR',1,NULL,1,0) CUR,
  o.client_no,
  D.CURRENCY
FROM
  bos_m_ledger o, bos_m_para r, bos_m_client c, bos_cltype g, BOS_M_STOCK D
WHERE
      r.para_type = 'BRANCH'
  AND R.PARA_CODE = O.BRANCH_CODE
  and o.client_no = c.client_no
  AND O.STOCK_NO = D.STOCK_NO
  and g.nbrk_rate = 1
  AND CSTAMP_EXPIRY_DATE IS NOT NULL
  and c.client_type = g.client_type
  and o.tdr_code = c.tdr_code
  and o.tran_type = 'CON'
  AND C.CLIENT_NO ='3JF0391'
  AND C.TDR_CODE >= 'DA1'
  AND C.TDR_CODE <= 'ZZZZZZ'
group by  
  substr(o.tran_no,1,1), o.client_no, o.branch_code, r.descr, c.client_name,
  C.TDR_CODE, D.CURRENCY, NVL(D.EXCH_CODE,0)
ORDER BY 
O.BRANCH_CODE, C.TDR_CODE, O.CLIENT_NO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN o.tran_no LIKE 'B%' THEN 'BUY'
             WHEN o.tran_no LIKE 'S%' THEN 'SELL'
        END) as BS_IND,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.tran_no LIKE 'B%' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) as Buy,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.tran_no LIKE 'S%' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) as sell,
       COALESCE(D.CURRENCY, 'MYR') as CURRENCY3,
       (CASE WHEN(D.CURRENCY = 'MYR' OR D.CURRENCY IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Cur)
       o.client_no, D.CURRENCY
FROM bos_m_ledger o JOIN
     bos_m_para r
     ON R.PARA_CODE = O.BRANCH_CODE JOIN
     bos_m_client c
     ON o.client_no = c.client_no AND o.tdr_code = c.tdr_code JOIN
     bos_cltype g
     ON c.client_type = g.client_type
     BOS_M_STOCK D
     ON O.STOCK_NO =D.STOCK_NO
WHERE r.para_type='BRANCH' AND
      g.nbrk_rate = 1 AND
      CSTAMP_EXPIRY_DATE IS NOT NULL AND 
      o.tran_type = 'CON' AND
      C.CLIENT_NO='3JF0391' AND
      C.TDR_CODE >='DA1' AND
      C.TDR_CODE <='ZZZZZZ'
group by (CASE WHEN o.tran_no LIKE 'B%' THEN 'BUY'
               WHEN o.tran_no LIKE 'S%' THEN 'SELL'
          END),
        o.client_no
ORDER BY O.CLIENT_NO;
```

Along the way, join the modern world:

- Explicit `JOIN` syntax has been part of the SQL language for over 25 years.  Use it.
- `decode()` is Oracle-specific.  Learn the proper SQL for conditional expressions.

Comment: i get the same result like my 1st image. what i need is pic 2 where the currency 'MYR' for 'BUY' will become one row. and also one row for 'SELL'. my friend suggest to use decode(nvl) but i didnt get the way.

Comment: i get the result with just little bit change using your code, however i need to find other way to make sure result will display 'MYR' not cur  ' sum(CASE WHEN D.CURRENCY ='MYR' OR D.CURRENCY IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Cur,'

Answer (score 0):

You can us this on the top of your sql

```
 with tab as
  (select 'buy'  bs_i, 10 buy,  0 sell, 'myr' cur, 1 cur1, '3jfo391' client, 'myr' currency 
   union all
   select 'buy'  bs_i, 11 buy,  0 sell, 'myr' cur, 1 cur1, '3jfo391' client, null  currency 
   union all
   select 'sell' bs_i,  0 buy, 11 sell, 'myr' cur, 1 cur1, '3jfo391' client, 'myr' currency 
   union all
   select 'sell' bs_i,  0 buy, 10 sell, 'myr' cur, 1 cur1, '3jfo391' client, null  currency 
  )
  select bs_i, sum(buy), sum(sell), max(cur), max(cur1), max(client), max(currency) 
  from tab
  group by bs_i;
```

o/p:

```
bs_i    sum  sum     max    max   max       max
buy      21    0     myr    1     3jfo391   myr
sell      0   21     myr    1     3jfo391   myr
```

Comment: I cannot use like this because that only sample client no. i have thousands data.